# Rubyの連続するif文

Tags: ruby

Rubyで４つの数字の平均を出して、平均より下の数字と上の数字を違う色にするプログラムを作りたいのですが、

```
#! ruby -Ks
#! ruby -Ks
# coding: windows-31j
# helloruby G05.rb
STDOUT.sync = true 

a = gets.chomp.to_i
b = gets.chomp.to_i
c = gets.chomp.to_i
d = gets.chomp.to_i
e =(a+b+c+d)/4.0

puts ""
print " 平均値="
puts e  

if e>a
print"\e[31m   \n"
puts a
else
print"\e[34m   \n"
puts a     

if e>b
print"\e[31m   \n"
puts b
else
print"\e[34m   \n"
puts b     

if e>c
print"\e[31m   \n"
puts c
else
print"\e[34m   \n"
puts c    

if e>d
print"\e[31m   \n"
puts d
else
print"\e[34m   \n"
puts d   

end
```

とすると

```
helloruby.rb:44:syntax error,unexpected end-of-input,expecting keyword\end
```

と言われます
どうすれば良いのでしょうか

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` は `end` で終わらせる必要があり、このプログラムにはかなりの数の `end` が不足しています。